# What is the meaning of this error (protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`)?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi i was installing firebase on the ubuntu console with `npm install --save firebase`
and got this error below in the installation process,
I tried to install `npm install protobufjs@6.11.2` to try to get rid of the error but it did not work.
What is the meaning of the error?

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 4):

npm attempts not to run the protobuff postinstall script as root and when you are trying to run it as a root using "sudo" command npm will try to prevent it. So you need to use --unsafe-perm flag while installing. So the full command will look like
`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g firebase`

Comment: This worked like a charm, If you need to use this on Windows just run
`npm install --unsafe-perm -g firebase` with a Git Bash opened as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this error occurs but my understanding is that it is related to some sort of permission issue.

You can solve this error by prefix **Sudo**

**sudo npm install --save firebas**